# Windows 7 will not boot

Tags: windows-7, windows

I deleted start-up files with cleaner and now the pc is will not boot up. I do not have the installation disk (as they do not provide one with pc's these days). How do I boot up? My other machine is a lap top.

Comment: Any idea at all what startup files you deleted? Does the system boot into Safe Mode? If so, did you try System Restore?

Comment: Deleting startup programs should not stop the system from booting. Are you sure that is the only damage you made.

Comment: [Do a system restore](http://www.pcworld.com/article/252927/restore_your_system_when_you_cant_launch_system_restore.html), pick a date before you cleaned things up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your laptop is installed with win,

Try creating a windows recovery disk to a USB in your laptop and use it to boot our PC.

You may follow this link https://www.winhelp.us/create-a-recovery-drive-in-windows-8.html

Update: i also found this from windows offical site.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/create-usb-recovery-drive

i think only difference is in win 8 its stated as recovery drive , in win 7 as recovery disk.

Comment: Are the instructions exactly the same as for Windows 7, which the OP is using?

Comment: Updated the answer :)